# How can Link my App to my Page (fan page)

Tags: facebook

I have a new app for linking a smf forum, That is working ok.

The thing is that I want to link my app to my forum fan page,

But when I enter to MyApps-> Advanced, only see the option to create a new one, and then only have the X button as an option for erase (no edit option), I'm in an infinite loop here, I can't link my app to my fan page...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8709480/where-is-the-facebook-add-to-page-to-add-an-app-to-a-fan-page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add tab application to a page with the "new auth dialog"](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8596217/how-to-add-tab-application-to-a-page-with-the-new-auth-dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL

YOUR_URL should contain the same value as Page Tab URL: in app settings